# Disable or reorder audio source and/or output

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone, driver, zoom

I have had a persistent issue with my macbook where I have a few audio devices that I never ever use, but that continue to show in the sound menus.

1. It's just annoying to have to sort through them when I just need to pick either headphones, stand-alone mic, or macbook mic/speakers, to have these other audio devices listed
2. In some situations, for example when starting zoom, the software will automatically pick one of these audio devices, and I'll need to manually override that. This may be a fault of zoom, but I hold no faith they will fix it, so I wonder if there is a way to simply remove certain audio devices from the macbook settings itself.

The one that is most troublesome is 'owc thunderbolt 3 audio device', which is the name listed in the menus for the microphone/headphone jacks on my thunderbolt hub. But to be clear, there are other devices listed I do not use but are still listed.

Ideally I would be able to control the list and disable or delete whatever I don't want to see, or at least order them so that the things I use are at the top and thus when the mac/zoom software auto-picks they pick in the order I prefer.

Is there some way to do that?

I am on Sonoma 14.2.1, if that matters.

Many thanks!